# Container exits after script is run in cloud run

Tags: google-cloud-run, data-pipeline

I have a Dockerfile that runs a python script to process a dataset and store in GCS. I've uploaded the image to GCR and I can run it with Cloud run. It runs fine except for the fact when the script execution is done, the container exits, see image.
[image]

This causes the service to fail.
How do I ensure that while the container is scaled down to 0 it doesn't report that the service failed.

Comment: Can you share your code? Your docker file and your python script (only the relevant piece of code)

Comment: Google Cloud Run is an HTTP Request/Response system. If you are running a script in the background that is ending execution, then the container is behaving the way you wrote it. Instead, wrap your script inside an HTTP request. Use a framework like Flask (Python) or one for your language. Your container entry point must start an HTTP service.